# SwiftのsendAsynchronousRequestが呼ばれない

Tags: swift

swiftで下記のような関数を作り、WebAPIと通信を試みましたが、この関数の中のsendAsynchronousRequestが実行されずに結果が帰ってきません。プリント文をこのメソッドの中に書き確認しました。

コード

```html
func requestList(order: String?, to: NSDate?, from: NSDate?, completion: ((response: NSURLResponse!, data: [Data]?, error: NSError?) -> Void)){
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ja_JP")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'"
        var urlStr = baseUrl
        if order != nil{
            urlStr += "\(formatParam)\(orderParam)" + order!
        }else{
            urlStr += "\(formatParam)"
        }
        if to != nil{
            let strTo = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(to!)
            urlStr += "\(toParam)\(strTo)"
        }
        if from != nil{
            let strFrom = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(from!)
            urlStr += "\(fromParam)\(strFrom)"
        }

        println(urlStr)
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlStr)!,
            cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
            timeoutInterval: 60.0)

        let queue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(req, queue: queue,
            completionHandler: {
                [unowned self]
                (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error :NSError!) -> Void in

                println("aaa")
                var jsonResult: NSDictionary? = nil
                var resultError: NSError? = error
                var resultData: [Data]?

                if error == nil{
                    jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &resultError) as? NSDictionary

                    if resultError == nil && jsonResult != nil{
                        resultData = self.parseDataList(jsonResult!)
                    }
                }
                completion(response: response, data: resultData, error: resultError)
            })
    }
```

テストは以下のようになっています。

テスト

```html
func testRequestList(){
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
        var order = "new"
        var to = NSDate.date(year: 2015, month: 9, day: 20)
        var from = NSDate.date(year: 2015, month: 8, day: 1)
        println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(to))
        println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(from))

        ApiController.sharedInstance.requestList(order, to: to, from: from, completion: {
            (resp: NSURLResponse!,
                data: [Data]?,
                error: NSError?) in
            var errorMessage: String?

            println("aaaa")
            if error != nil{
                println(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            println("aaa")
            println(data!)
            for d in data!{
                println(d.temperature)
            }

        })

    }
```

ブラウザでURLの正しさは確認済みです。Swift初心者なので初歩的な質問かも知れませんがご教授ねがえますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: これだけでははっきりとは分かりませんが、レスポンスが帰ってくる前にアプリケーションが終了しているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとう御座います。
そのようでした。`waitForExpectationsWithTimeout`というものを用いることで実行できました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の変更をしたところうまく動きました。

```html
func testRequestList(){
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
        var order = "new"
        var to = NSDate.date(year: 2015, month: 9, day: 20)
        var from = NSDate.date(year: 2015, month: 8, day: 1)
        println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(to))
        println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(from))
        //追加
        let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Finish")

        ApiController.sharedInstance.requestList(order, to: to, from: from, completion: {
            (resp: NSURLResponse!,
                data: [Data]?,
                error: NSError?) in
            var errorMessage: String?

            println("aaaa")
            if error != nil{
                println(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            println("aaa")
            for d in data!{
                println(d.temperature)
            }
            //追加
            expectation.fulfill()

        })
        //追加
        self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(1, handler: nil)
```